# update Age. The Age are above 100 years in the table HMT

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

The Age Column has a negative value -44 and two other values of 180 and 240.

```
UPDATE HMT
SET Age = '18', '24'
WHERE Age ='180' , '240';
```

I was expecting the age to change to 18 and 24 respectively.

Comment: Never store age. People become older all the time, and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store date of birth instead.

Comment: What happened when you executed that query? I would expect an error as this syntax is wrong. The easiest way is to convert 180->18 and 240->24 in separate updates. And is that age really a string?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
UPDATE HMT
SET Age = CStr(Val([Age]) / 10)
WHERE Age In ('180','240')
```

or, it Age is numeric:

```sql
UPDATE HMT
SET Age = [Age] / 10
WHERE Age In (180,240)
```